# How to: Adding icon/sign besides every returned search result?

Tags: 2007, search, web-part

**How to create a web application level feature that displays a small icon/sign that is located besides every returned search results ?**

The Client wants a custom web part for MOSS 2007 and SP 2010, whenever hs uses the Search. He wants to see a small printer icon/sing that is located besides every single returned search result, and if the User clicked on it then it should print out the page of that particular search result.

The Printing functionality is OK, **But, How to display icon next to every search result ?**

BTW, the Client has 3 projects (2 of them are MOSS 2007 and one is SP 2010), that's why he asked a generic web part in order to use it with all projects.

I would greatly appreciate any inputs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Core Result Web Part for rendering your results, then you will have to modify the xslt for the web part and add in rendering code for your print icon and click logic.

On SP2010 you could for example change the following part of the xslt which shows the file type icon

```
<div class="srch-Icon" id="{concat($currentId,'_Icon')}">
   <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="srch-Icon" id="{concat($currentId,'_Icon')}">
   <img align="absmiddle" src="{imageurl}" border="0" alt="{imageurl/@imageurldescription}" />
   <img src="path/printicon.gif" onclick="myprintfunction()" />
</div>
```

Where path/printicon.gif points to your print icon, and myprintfunction() does your print logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is explained here:

http://sharepointblog.dk/post/2009/07/21/Skift-ikoner-i-sc3b8geresultatet.aspx

The article is in Danish, but you should be able to translate it using Google Translate, or similar...